# Overleaf does not find image anymore after recompiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

I am using Overleaf and TikZ to draw an image of a map with nodes (Cities) on top.

This is my code so far:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{lager} = [regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw=green!60, fill = green!10, inner sep = 1pt];
        \tikzstyle{standort} = [rectangle, draw = blue!60, fill = blue!10];
        \node[above right,opacity=0.3,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{./Bilder/"Karte_Deutschland".pdf}};
        \node[lager, label=right:Nullpunkt] (Koeln) at (0,0) {0};
        \node[standort, label=right:Düsseldorf] (Duesseldorf) at (1.5,10) {2};
        \node[standort, label=right:Frankfurt] (Frankfurt) at (5,8) {4};
        \node[standort, label=left:München] (Muenchen) at (11,4) {4};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionof{figure}{Test Image.}
        \label{fig:test123}
\end{figure}
```

When I open the document from my list of documents, the images compiles correctly.
However, if I use the recompile-button, the following error is shown:

> Package pdftex.def Error: File `./Bilder/Karte_Deutschland.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

The "Recompile from scratch"-option does not help either.
I suppose this is some caching-issue, however it can be very tiresome to exit and reenter the document everytime I want to see the changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you contacted the Overleaf Helpdesk? I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: Off-topic: Why do you write `\captionof{figure}{Test Image.}`? Why not `\caption{Test Image.}`?

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I will try contacting them as well. On the Off-topic: I am new to Latex and still need to copy lots of stuff from the Internet. I most likely got this somewhere else and just copied it :)

Comment: Image file name `"Karte_Deutschland".pdf` is unusual. Try to use just `Karte_Deutschland` (without `"` around name, also file extension `.pdf` is not needed.

Comment: also things are much simpler if you put the pdf file in the same directory as the document and use `{Karte_Deutschland.pdf}` not `{./Bilder/Karte_Deutschland.pdf}`  as the relative path depends on details of the build process.

Comment: You can not get a message about UNC `\\ ` paths if you do not tell latex that path exists. Once you have set up `m:` to be that folder use `m:/yourfile` in the latex document (as you had it originally)